# Twilio - can't send SMS messages to just anyone?

Tags: twilio

I'm new to Twilio - can you send SMS messages to just anyone? It seems like it requires me to verify each and every single phone number I'd like to send messages to rather than letting me send to any one of my users.

Is this true? Is there a way I can send messages to any of my ITSM users without having to preverify their phone number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio employee here. This is a restriction for trial accounts only. Once you add a credit card to your account, you will be able to send messages to any number you would like (based on the international permissions in your account, etc).